# Redirect 301 URL using Nginx server

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

how to redirect 301 url

from `STRING?page=NBR`

to  `STRING/NBR/`

in NGINX server.

Comment: Please include your conf.

Comment: yes, but what can i add to conf, like this code                                                   # nginx configuration
location / {
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 redirect;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try it. I think that the ideas will help you.

```
location = STRING {    
    if ($arg_page) { return 301 STRING/$arg_page/; }
}
```

or

```
location = STRING {    
    if ($arg_page) { rewrite STRING STRING/$arg_page/ permanent; }
}
```

> **$arg_name** - argument name in the request line

Added as example for random STRING:

```
server {    
    if ($arg_page) { return 301 $uri/$arg_page/; }
}
```

> **$uri** - current URI in request, normalized. The value of $uri may change during request processing, e.g. when doing internal redirects, or when using index files.
>
> **return** ... As a special case, a redirect URL can be specified as a URI local to this server, in which case the full redirect URL is formed according to the request scheme ($scheme) and the server_name_in_redirect and port_in_redirect directives.

Or:

```
server {    
    if ($arg_page) { return 301 $scheme://$server_name$uri/$arg_page/; }
}
```

> **$scheme** - request scheme, “http” or “https”
>
> **$server_name** - name of the server which accepted a request
>
> **if ($arg_page)** - false if the value of a variable is an empty string or “0”

Comment: but My STRING is random string or part of url, how can replace STRING by any random string

Comment: There are many ways. For example, `location / {}` match all your URLs. Or use `if` in all locations. And use regexp for STRING. Please include your config.

Comment: Try third example.